# First moment of area

Tags: integration, area

If I wanted to calculate $$\int y\ dA,$$ it can be re-written as $$\int y.x\ dy$$ when possible. That is by taking a small strip parallel to the $x$ axis. Similarly, can it be re-written as $$\int y.y\ dx$$ also (by taking a small strip parallel to the $y$ axis)?

Answer (score 1):

It is correct only for a straight edge boundary. $ x/y = const, \quad x dy - ydx =0 $

Answer (score 0):

No, because in $\int y\cdot y dy$ the value of the integrand $y$ is not a constant over the (vertical) strip.

Comment: **then how do I find the value of $$\int_0^1 ydA$$ for y = 4+2x-x^2?**

Answer (score 0):

Not quite.  The reason your first form works is that what is going on is really

$\displaystyle \int y dA = \int y dx dy = \int y dy \int dx = \int y x dy$

If you do it in reverse order, you do the integation over $y$ first

$\displaystyle \int y dA = \int dx \int y dy = ???$

I will leave it to you to show that this does not give quite what you thought.

And note that you haven't said anything about the limits of the integration, which will add further complications.